# ASMX Web Services + Active Directory question

Tags: web-services, active-directory, asmx

I have a client that calls a web service that then hits AD to get information.

Recently i started to have the following behavior.

after a long wait or a IISReset, the Client calls the web service,
the web service shows the call, starts to DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache();.
(Which is inside a try catch that should log any exceptions)

Then nothing happens.

A couple min later, I see activity on the same thread in the web service logs,

but no error ever shows up in the service or the client logs, just nothing.

Eventually after a long wait, the web service will start working fine, and calling the
exact same function will result in a response in a reasonable time.

interestingly the call to the Web service that's hanging is NOT the first call that
hits ad, it's a couple calls down. (So in theory it's not the initial connection, an issue we had before, and had to set connectionprotection=none on the membership provider to fix )

So my questions are,
does the recurrence of the thread in the log file indicate that the thread has been
terminated?
If it's terminated why don't I get an error, it's in a try catch?

any idea why DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache() is taking so long?

Comment: Turns out i was wrong, RefreshCace() goes off just fine.
but when copying the DEs properties to my local copy, it' just stops

either on objectCategory or nTSecurityDescriptor then nothing...

Is it possible that it's memory corruption?

What does a webservice do if a thread has memory corruption, does it kill it quietly? Does the Thread get recycled in the thread pool?

I'd sort of expect an exception of some kind, atleast on the webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weird webservice thread never returning or throwing and error,  turned out to most likey be a Memory Corruption bug in the Class Library I was using, which copied the properties to a local copy.

Using memorycorruption as my best guess, I re wrote it without using the library, to just get the value I was after, and the issue went away.

Thanks,

Eric-